# Mosaico: Packages are missing (Beta 4)

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mosaico, 5.0

Just upgraded to Beta 4 - getting the following error.

> Mosaico: Packages are missing Mosaico requires dependencies in its
>   "packages" folder. Please consult the README.md for current
>   installation instructions.

Wordpress 4.9.7
Civi 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "releases" on GitHub don't include the dependencies and aren't supposed to be downloaded directly for "consumption" - the supported workflow is either to use the advanced instructions in the readme file (running install.sh) or to install using the tarball from the CiviCRM extensions directory.

The final build process for mosaico merges GitHub repos to create the tarball.

**Extensions Directory page:**
https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder

**Chat discussion on the same issue:**
https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/p7ih3bq36trp5frqnmccy1o3fy