# "New Mailing" doesn't take me to Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

We've had Mosaico installed for a while, and we like it, however, I don't think it is behaving as it should in our installation. Here is what I *think* should happen:

1. Select Mailings / New Mailing
2. A Mailing editor opens up, which is different than the "Traditional" editor. This Mosaico Mailing editor shows Mosaico templates as thumbnails, rather than a drop-down list. Such as https://wapix.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/001-1200x561.png
3. Select the Mosaico template
4. The Mosaico editor opens and you edit your message with all of the Mosaico features.

Here is how our installation behaves:

1. Select Mailings / New Mailing
2. The Traditional mailing editor opens. Mosaico templates are listed in the drop-down box.
3. When a Mosaico template is selected, the code is placed in the CKEditor as if it were any normal message. No Mosaico drag-and-drop capabilities are available. See image. [image: Mosaico template in old Mailing editor]
4. To use the Mosaico features, we have to use the template editor, save the template, and then base a new Mailing on that template in the old "traditional" editor.

For the longest time, I thought this was just a quirky behavior -- create a new Mosaico Template for *every* mailing, and then put that into the traditional Mailing editor. I've since started to suspect that this is not the case.

Can I get some confirmation that this is, in fact, incorrect behavior? And, any ideas as to why this is happening?

Joomla 3.9.2, Civi 5.9.0

Comment: what version of Mosaico do you have? has it ever been upgraded and if so can you remember from which version?

Comment: It certainly sounds like you're using Mosaico 1.x, not 2.x.

Comment: True, we are using 1.1. Should have mentioned that. I had installed 2.0beta4 in our development site, and got the "missing dependencies" error (as described in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25763/mosaico-packages-are-missing-beta-4). I didn't work through that error, as I wasn't sure I wanted a beta on my production site anyway. But if it will solve this problem, it might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks Pete and Jon. Mosaico 2.0 does what I want, and I was able to install it properly from https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-civicrm-integration/version-20-beta4